# Difference between an "controlled ODE" and a "non-homogeneous ODE"

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

In control theory one consider so called "controlled odes" i.e $X^{'}=AX+Bu$ where $u$ is the controll or input and $X$ is the "state". This in turn is describing a controlled dynamical system.

In the theory of ODEs we have homogeneous and non-homogeneous ODEs. The non-homogeneous often taking the form say, $y^{'}+Ay=u$ for some given function $u$.

Is there any essential difference between these to notions? I cannot think of any.

Comment: In ODE theory $u$ is considered some function of $t$ while in control theory $u$ is chosen in order to achieve certain specifications and usually is in the form of "feedback" which means that $u=u(x,t)$. As a result the corresponding ODE form changes if for example $u=Kx+r(t)$ then $\dot{x}=(A+BK)x+r(t)$ with different homogeneous solution that the original ODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the the non-homogeneous ODE case $u$ would be a function of time. The response of the system will be a sum of the transient and steady-state response of the system. The transient will only depend of the initial conditions of $x$ and $A$, so a homogeneous solution. This transient response of the system will die out eventually if the system is stable. For a linear time invariant state space model this is the case when all the eigenvalues of $A$, also known as the poles, have negative real part. The steady-state will depend on $u$, $A$ and $B$.

In the controlled ODE case $u$ could be a function of both time and the state $x$. The fact that $u$ can be a function of $x$ means that one will be able to alter the dynamics of the system, so change the location of the poles. This, if the pair $(A,B)$ is controllable/stabilizable, allows you to turn an unstable system into a stable one.

So to summarize, the non-homogeneous ODE only allows you to change the steady-state of the system (which only "exists" if the system is stable by itself). While the controlled ODE allows you to change both the transient and the steady-state.

Comment: When you say respone of system, do you mean solution?

Comment: @user1 Yes. Where the transient response refers to the homogeneous solution and the steady state response to the non-homogeneous solution obtained by setting the initial conditions to zero.

Comment: I have been thinking about the following you wrote " The fact that $u$ can be a function of $x$ means that one will be able to alter the dynamics of the system". Do you mind eleborating on your statement?

Comment: @user1 For example the simple system $\dot{x}=x+u$ is (openloop) unstable. So when picking $u(t)=\sin(t)$, then $x$ will exponentially grow to infinity. While $u(t,x)=\sin(t)-2\,x$ will not. So the fact of adding $-2\,x$ to the expression for $u$ kind of changes the homogeneous solution of the system.

Comment: oh, I tought homogenus solution was the one where $u=0$. What do you mean by homogenous sol.?

Comment: @user1 You are correct, but that is why I said that it kind of changes it. So I should have specified that I consider the (semi) homogeneous solution as the solution where the time dependency of $u$ is set to zero (so still allowing $u$ to depend on $x$).

Comment: so once we appiled some control and separated the part depedant of $t$ and the one affecting the dynamic then we are in the "standard" ode situation? Given that it is possible to seperate the effects.